# Why does ADL fail on a dependent typename?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

I noticed that `get<0>(t)` fails to be resolved to `std::get<0>(t)` if its argument's type depends on a template parameter:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T) {
  std::tuple<T> tup{0};
  get<0>(tup) = 1; // error: 'get' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'std::get'?
}
```

This works fine if `foo` is not a template (i.e. if `tup` is declared as `std::tuple<int>`) or with `using std::get;`. Shouldn't it also work in a function template where ADL is often extra useful?

Answer (score 5):

This was changed in C++20 ([P0846R0](https://wg21.link/P0846R0)).

Before C++20, `get<0>(tup) = 1` is parsed as `get < 0 > (tup) = 1` (get is less than zero is greater than tup is assigned to one). Since `get` doesn't exist, this won't compile.

In C++20, a new rule was added so it's interpreted as a *template-name* when nothing is found, allowing it to be interpreted as calling a function template.

The pre-C++20 fix is to declare a function template in scope, even if it it won't ultimately be selected:

```cpp
// Make it difficult to call this by accident
template<template<template<int> class> class>
void get() = delete;

template <typename T>
void foo(T) {
  std::tuple<T> tup{0};
  // lookup for `get` finds the global function template, so this is
  // parsed as a call to a template function
  get<0>(tup) = 1;
}
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/dPG9ah8fo

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a compiler error on gcc up to and including 10.2. Subsequent versions fix this.

Comment: I found this when preparing an example on compiler explorer for the question and decided to post the already written question. Answers with evidence from the standard are welcome, still.

Comment: What is really interesting is if you compile target C++20/C++2a the code does compile in the older versions: https://godbolt.org/z/c89Mboq3n

Comment: @NathanOliver No it doesn't. Your example passes because `foo` is never instantiated --- gcc can see that nobody in this compilation unit want it, so it doesn't bother. If you call `foo(0);` in main, it fails to compile.